# Are push-connect sockets intended to be reusable?

Tags: lamp, socket

are push connection light sockets a one time use only.  I disconnected the lamp cord to replace it but now the wire holes will not grip the wire.

Comment: Please add detail about your particular device. The question is impossible to answer conclusively as it is.

Comment: Can you post photos of the socket in question?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the light socket, and maybe how you "disconnected" it.  Some push-in type wire connectors are actually threaded; they grip when you just push them in, but you can back the wires out by twisting them (lefty loosey).  However, if the wires were yanked out, it's possible that the threads were stripped and won't grip any more.  I assume you have also checked for small screws. Sometimes connections that look like push-ins are actually clamps.  You stick the wire in the hole, and then clamp it down (internally) by tightening a screw.